# How do I write a route in ZF2 that cater for GET Parameters?

Tags: php, parameters, routes, zend-framework2

How do I write a route in zf2 that allows for routes like `/:controller/:action/*` in zf1?

So that it can cater for parameters like *`controller/action/id/1/page/2`* and *`controller/action?id=1&page=2`* ?

A route that caters for parameters like *`controller/action?id=1&page=2`* world be useful for ajax requests.

So my current code looks like this in my **module.config.php**

```
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Support\Controller\Support' => 'Support\Controller\SupportController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'support' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/support[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Support\Controller\Support',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'support' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

A look at the docs for [Zend\Mvc\Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.intro.html) and a quick root around in the [module.config.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php) file for the Application module in the [Zend Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) tell me that you need to set up a [route segment](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment) router that will match the url's you want to create.

As well as the Zend Framework docs, there is this slide show [introduction to routing in Zend Framework](http://evan.pro/zf2-router-talk.html#slide1) which you may find useful. It has code  examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I've based my application off the Skeleton Application and I've read through the slide show link you gave. It does say for a segment route that it does support optional segments (both literal and parameter parts). 

I'm just not quite sure how. Maybe I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following question and answer:

[How can you add query parameters in the ZF2 url view helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785190/how-can-you-add-query-parameters-in-the-zf2-url-view-helper)

I would attempt to set-up a route and then adding a child route that uses `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Query`.