# How to add parameters to controller redirect?

Tags: redirect, parameters, controller, action, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2 I want to pass an array of parameters from one action to another within the same controller which I did in ZF1 in the following manner:

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoSimple('foo', null, null, $params);
```

and in fooAction:

```
$params = $this->_request->getParams();
```

In ZF2, trying the various answers I have seen here on SO, I came up with the following:

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('home/default', array(
            'controller' => 'client',
            'action' => 'foo',
            'param' => 'bar'),
        array('param' => 'bar'));
```

(trying both the $params and $options arguments of toRoute())

and in fooAction:

```
$param = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
```

or

```
$param = $this->params()->fromRoute());
```

None works for me. Is there a simple way to achieve what I want (passing parameters with a redirect) or should I go the route of using a container, session or even global variables?

Comment: That should work perfectly well, are you sure your route is setup correctly?
Are you making sure your controller implements InjectApplicationEvent (or extends the ZF2 Abstract controller provided)

Comment: No, I haven't set up the parameters in my route. If I do that, it works indeed. But that means that I have to set up a route for each individual action with params. The beauty in ZF1 was that you could use a one for all (segment) route and set up individual params in your controller.

Comment: But you are using toRoute(), obviously this requires a route to work with ;)

Comment: If you want to pass parameters as query string, here's your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15422349/1154069 .
To access in controller, use $this->params()->fromQuery('paramName');

Comment: @Andrew: yes, that was were the real problem was, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what I did was, instead of using route parameters, using query parameters, since the parameters I used where not route related. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the forward plugin:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-forward-plugin

```
public function someAction()
{
    $returnValue = $this->forward()->dispatch('application/controller/index', array(
        'action' => 'other'
    ));

    return $returnValue;
}

public function otherAction()
{
    return 99;
}
```

You will be able to pass parameters too

Comment: But as far as I can see, in order to make that work, I need to set up the parameters in a route. And that was not necessary in ZF1.