# Query is deprecated in Zendfamework 2.1.4

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

```
'login' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/giris',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'zfcuser',
            'action'     => 'login',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'provider' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:provider',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'provider' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'ScnSocialAuth-User',
                    'action' => 'provider-login',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'query' => array(
            'type' => 'Query',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Giving message Deprecated: Query route deprecated as of ZF 2.1.4; use the "query" option of the HTTP router's assembling method instead in /opt/lampp/KendindenApp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Query.php on line 21

It works fine When i remove this lines.

```
'query' => array(
    'type' => 'Query',
),
```

Comment: Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785190/how-can-you-add-query-parameters-in-the-zf2-url-view-helper/15422349#15422349

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have deprecated the query route in ZF 2.1.4 for security reasons. For more details, please refer to http://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2013-01

Comment: Thats cool (the deprecation that is), but how can I set constraints and defaults for query parameters via the route configuration now?

Comment: For this you can define type as segment in route configuration.
[http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment)

Comment: @NitinKumarSoni, you linked to documentation for a version pre-deprecation! This could be very confusing.

This link at least says deprecated - http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment