# ZF2 - Retain query from form using url helper in pagination

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm new to ZF2 and I'm willing to share how I do to retain parameter from form using url helper especially during pagination. I modify the answer from [How can you add query parameters in the ZF2 url view helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785190/how-can-you-add-query-parameters-in-the-zf2-url-view-helper)

This is what I do:

**AlbumController.php**

```
// get all the query from url
$input = $form->getData();

$paginator = $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll();
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int)$this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1));
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(30);

// unset the 'page' query if necessary
unset($input['page']);

return array(
    'form'   => $form,
    'paginator' => $paginator,
    'routeParams' => array_filter($input) // filter empty value
);
```

**index.phtml**

```
echo $this->paginationControl(
    $this->paginator,
    'sliding',
    array('partial/paginator.phtml', 'Album'),
    array(
        'route' => 'album',
        'routeParams' => $routeParams
    )
);
```

**paginator.phtml**

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(
                    $this->route, // your route name
                    array(),      // any url options, e.g action
                    array('query' => $this->routeParams) // your query params
               ); 
echo (empty($this->routeParams))?  '?' : '&'; ?>
page=<?php echo $this->next; ?>">Next Page</a>
```

Please provide any better solution and correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a much better solution than yours - I don't see a proper way to retain existing query params while adding some new ones. But the following is neater than manually appending & and = characters:

#### paginator.phtml

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(
    $this->route, // your route name
    array(),      // any url options, e.g action
    // Merge the array with your new value(s)
    array('query' => array('page' => $this->next) + $this->routeParams)
); ?>">Next Page</a>
```

This will also ensure that if you already have a `page` param, it will be overwritten by the new one.

(Technically you could also use `$_GET` or `$_POST` directly and avoid passing it from the controller at all, but that doesn't seem very neat)