# ZF2 Create route like " login?url=foo "

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

I'm struggling on this for 2 hours now. I've managed to create a route with parameter (named `url`) like `/login/url`:

```
'login' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/login[/:url]',
        'defaults' => array(
             'controller' => 'my_controller',
             'action'     => 'login',
        ),
    ),
),
```

However I'd like to have an URL which looks like `/login?url=foo`. I've tried something like:

```
'route'    => '/login[?url=:url]',
```

But it does not work. Any idea how to achieve this on Zend Framework 2 ?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**
Trying something else like:

```
// onBootstrap method --> redirect to login page with request url as param    
$url = $router->assemble(
    array('url', $e->getRequest()->getRequestUri()),
    array('name' => 'login')
);
```

In controller (login action):

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
var_dump($request); exit;
```

I don't see the requested URL anywhere... any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should put your query string segment in your route. It would seem reasonable to have your route to be just `/login` and then manage your query string parameter in the controller.

Otherwise, but I don't recommend it since it is deprecated, you could try to use the [Query router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-query-deprecated).

Comment: Just edited my post. I'm trying to do it your way be I can't get it to work.  Any idea?

Comment: You could access the query parameters in your controller with `$this->params()->fromQuery()`. Moreover, to do the redirect it'll probably help to use http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#redirect-plugin

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've done every step specified in the doc: assemble route, inject location and set status code. But still nothing in the controller... and the documentation is very poor on how `$params` and `$options` can be used (`assemble` method parameters).

Comment: When you want to do the redirect, try to do `return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login', [], ['query' => ['url' => $url]]);`

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. Now I think I got it (hopefully...); you should use `$router->assemble([], ['name' => 'login', 'query' => ['url' => $url]])`

Comment: It works thanks! I'm curious where did you get the info about the `query` key?

Comment: I had just in my code, didn't know where I first found it. It is not well documented, you probably just need to read the code. Otherwise it is mentioned somewhere like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15422349/2718064